# How to append a char* to the end of a void*?

Tags: c++, pointers, append, libcurl

Assume we have defined a char* as follow:

```
char *x;
```

And we have a function like it:

```
void append(void *y, char *z);
```

This function appends it's second parameter (where the pointer **z** is pointing at) to the end of a string that the pointer **y** is pointing to it's beginning. The reason that I am restricted to have the first parameter to be **void*** is that I need to override a [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION.html) function:

```
size_t header_callback(char *buffer, size_t size, size_t nitems, void *userdata);
```

Any time the header_callback function is called I need to append buffer to the end of userdata. The userdata pointer is pointing to beginning of a string.

Comment: Is `void* y` pointing to a `std::string`? Or a `char` buffer?

Comment: Having just a naked pointer and appending to it is quite unsafe unless you can make sure you're not going out of bounds.

Comment: Cast the `void` pointer back to whatever type you provided in the first place, perform whatever operations you require, an carry on. Make sure you provide `size *nitems` as you can't count on the usual string copying tricks to work with `buffer`.

Comment: @Galik, void* y should point to a char.

Comment: Avoid using a `char *` to back `y`. It tragically over-complicates the code you need to write in a world where `std::string`, `std::stringstream` and possibly even `std::vector` can do what you need with three lines of code or less.

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation you linked, *userdata* is a pointer previously supplied to *CURLOPT_HEADERDATA*. Something like this might work for you.

```
size_t header_callback(char *buffer, size_t size, size_t nitems, vector<string> *userdata)
{
    userdata->push_back(string(buffer, size*nitems));
    return size*nitems;
}

//...
vector<string> headers;
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADERDATA, &headers);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, header_callback);
//...
```

Comment: One should to define new callbacks for custom HEADERDATA, be default it must be FILE*

Comment: @Swift `CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION` is the new callback, so the default of `CURLOPT_HEADERDATA` does not apply. @Bediver, the last argument of the callback must be `void*` to match the required prototype.

Comment: @user2079303 only if both functions redefined too and OP _had_ set a new value with CURLOPT_WRITEDATA option.  Again , too many unknowns. Out of all what he did write I have impression that it was set to char*, that's why append() use

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to implement your

> ```
> void append(void *y, char *z);
> ```

in such a way that it could append a non-null terminated character sequence.

The `char *buffer` given to the callback is non-null terminated.

Also, you can convert the void pointer to the correct type of the buffer in the callback, before calling the append. That must be done eventually, since you cannot append anything to void.

You hardly need an external function since appending is quite trivial. Assuming your `void*` points to a `std::string`:

```
auto bytes = size * nitems;
auto str = (std::string*)userdata;
str->append(buffer, bytes);
```

Comment: the problem is that append() can't "grow" the target buffer. especially if that was one from std::string. We should preallocate proper buffer and ensure that append won't run outside of it

Comment: @Swift Why couldn't append grow the target buffer? Especially if it is a `std::string`, it has inbuilt functionality for growing. You cannot preallocate accurately unless you know the length of the response before sending the request. Which you often do not, when you deal with communication protocols.

Comment: we do not know, that we _own_ the buffer, that is, if we can alter its storage... We may know length of answer if we know length of provided strings.    the offered code creates a new buffer with data collated from sources by means of std::string class... but it might be illegal even to try to return it. The prototypes presented do not look like returning  of buffer address is allowed.

Comment: @Swift we don't need to own the buffer. We have a (non-owning) pointer to the `std::string` and that string object owns the buffer wholly. It is completely safe for the string to grow its own buffer (unless of course there are iterators/pointers to the buffer, but the user of those iterators know (or at least they really should know) that the callback must be able to invalidate the buffer).

Comment: we dealing with callbacks here, callbacks _typically_ do not own storage passed to them. but output of that string can be written by fwrite to FILE* if OP uses default userdata callback, then it can be contained this way indeed. We can't return that buffer even if we had means for that because it either temporary or we'll leak created string.

Comment: @Swift The callback  does not own, and does not need to own the storage. The object pointed by `userdata` owns the storage, which is completely fine. Just like whatever system is associated with `FILE*` owns the file resource.

Comment: Oh,  sorry, your snipped  mislead me to belive  you try to do append operation with buffers, treating userdata as buffer. You could not cast to string though. what is proper is either to use _actual_ write call back or specially designed write method  for the structure behind the  userdata.

Comment: @Swift if `void*` points to a `std::string`, then of course you can, and should cast it.

Answer (score 0):

To append data to buffer  those things should be defined:

- allowed size of destination buffer
- amount of data in buffer present in destination buffer
- amount of data to be copied to destination buffer

In C realloc() can be used to create new buffer with content of old one.. that may or may not change location of buffer. In C++ there is flavor of new  operator that allows similar action.

If we assume that data stored is strictly null-terminated string (but even that  wasn't specified!) then 2nd and 3rd are known - the size of buffer is unknown to append() is size of buffer. Therefore, the function

```
void append(void *y, char *z);
```

looks either unfit for the task or very unsafe and possibly ill-defined, <s>unless  void *y is actually some structure or class (but passing that as void*???)</s> .

You did not provide implementation OR description of it. By the look is should be rather limited one. We should pre-allocate a buffer of proper size and ensure that append() won't run outside of its bounds. It cannot reallocate target buffer, so it is limited by *already* allocated memory. To actually reallocate target buffer append would have `void **y` or `void &* y` as formal parameter (realloc() *may* change pointer and *does* copy data from old buffer to new buffer)

This poses an architecture problem - ownership of buffer. If we pass buffer we control, we can allocate it properly and pass it to append() OR pass ownership to append() so it would reallocate it. If we don't, we have to create a temporal buffer... but can we use that temporal buffer afterwards?

The point is moot unless you are using  custom header write function. user data  pointer is CURLOPT_HEADERDATA, which is either pointer  to valid FILE and you should _fwrite() data to it... Or, if you are implementing CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION and CURLOPT_READFUNCTION callback, that pointer can be used at discretion of designer of callbacks, as a pointer to some useful data container (libcurl uses fwrite as default callback).

Answer (score -1):

Your question looks more referring to C (not C++) approach. Then you need the following:

1. know the size of the y
2. realloc the y to be of the size + 1
3. memcpy/memmove y to the new place
4. set the last byte of the new buffer to z
5. return to the user the pointer and the size of the new buffer
6. free the old buffer y (depends on the need).

In C++ hovewer you need to use some container like std::vector, which will allow you to append one byte.

Comment: Bad question to answer. Too many unknowns. For example, there may be no need to resize the buffer.

Comment: Then downwote the question, not the answer.